# JNI - connecting STDOUT to a JTextArea?

Tags: java, c++, swing, applet, java-native-interface

I am wondering if it is possible to connect STDOUT of a C/C++ dll to a JTextArea? The thing is, I am using 3rd party DLL's so I can't manually alter them. 
Basically I have my Java applet, and then my own DLL which Loads and manages the 3rd party DLL's, and it is the 3rd part DLL's which do stuff like printf(). It shows up in Eclipse console during debugging, but I want it in a JTextArea or something.

EDIT: To clarify, I am using std::cout in my win32 DLL.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is STDOUT?  If it's the Posix file handle, there's not much you can
do.  You'd have to close it, then open a temporary file, write to that,
and then read it in the Java part.  If you're actually using std::cout
for the output, it's possible to (temporarily) change the streambuf of
it to use a stringbuf, then pass the generated string to Java.

Comment: Yeah, I am using a std::cout in c++ win32. Can you elaborate on how to do it?

Comment: Something like:
`
    std::stringbuf str;
    std::streambuf* save = std::cout.rdbuf();
    std::cout.rdbuf(&str);
    //  the output...
    std::cout.rdbuf(save);  // Better would be to use RAII
    //  Now convert str.str() to a Java string.
`
Of course, if your code is outputting to an `std::ostream`, like it
should be, there's no problem: just use `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what I have to do to get the code in the above comment to format correctly?

Comment: 1. Do you know if you can stream directly into the textspace of a JTextArea?    2. 'str' and 'save' aren't meant to be used both at the same time I take it?      3. is there any better way than having a thread running and when it detects input in the buffer, convert to java string and print it out?

Comment: @KaiserJohaan Almost certainly not.  You'll almost certainly have to create a java.lang.String object, and pass that into the JTextArea object.  (The text space in the JTextArea is a Document, which is itself a complicated class, which may contain nested Document, etc.  It's not a simple buffer.)

Comment: @KaiserJohaan re your second question: in theory, there's no problem doing something with save while cout is still using the string.  That's not really the intention, however, and doing so is likely to confuse anyone reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could, in your DLL, redirect stdout to a file or pipe. Then you could read from the file or pipe in Java and copy what you read to your JTextArea. Another option would be to move your DLL into its own process, which you would start from Java, then read from the process's stdout and write to your JTextArea.

SetStdHandle [(link to MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will allow you to redirect stdout.

Comment: I'm having difficulty finding a way of opening a pipe in Java. If that turns out to be impossible, an alternative would be for your DLL to make stdout available as a socket. The method would be something like this: (1) Create a pipe. (2) SetStdHandle to set stdout to the writable end of the pipe. (3) Create a socket, bind to a port and wait for connection. (4) When a client is connected, read from the pipe and write its data to the socket. (5) In Java, connect to the port and copy data from it to the JTextArea.